# What does "have a year for every trombone that led the big parade" mean?

Tags: meaning

In REVIVAL written by Stephen King, when its main character (who works at a recording studio) asks for a couple-of-months-break, his boss says with a sigh, "Come this fall, I'm going to have a year for every trombone that led the big parade." I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 7):

It means he's going to be 76 in the autumn ("fall"). It's a reference to a song from the 1957 music [*The Music Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventy-Six_Trombones) by Meredith Willson (1902–1984):

> Seventy-six trombones led the big parade
>   With a hundred and ten cornets close at hand.
>   They were followed by rows and rows of the finest virtuo-
>   Sos, the cream of ev'ry famous band.
>   Seventy-six trombones caught the morning sun
>   With a hundred and ten cornets right behind
>   There were more than a thousand reeds
>   Springing up like weeds
>   There were horns of ev'ry shape and kind.
>   There were copper bottom tympani in horse platoons
>   Thundering, thundering all along the way.
>   Double bell euphoniums and big bassoons,
>   Each bassoon having its big, fat say!
>   There were fifty mounted cannon in the battery
>   Thundering, thundering louder than before
>   Clarinets of ev'ry size
>   And trumpeters who'd improvise
>   A full octave higher than the score!
>
> Lyrics via [stlyrics.com](http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/themusicman/seventy-sixtrombones.htm)

The first line at least has become quite famous, probably because of the catchy rhythm of triplets in the anacrucis (demonstrated in a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k98z-iTmwXA) chosen at random).